# the list item sign and the list inner content

Tags: html, css

when I code like that,the last list item is colored blue, but the list sign itself is still uncolored

```
<font color="blue">
      <li>man
      <li>woman
      <li>body
      <li>girl
      <li>baby
      </font>
```

but when I code like these, the list sign and the inner stuff are both colored

```
<font color="blue">
      <li>man
      <li>woman
      <li>body
      <li>girl
      <li>baby</li>
      </font>

<font color="blue">
      <li>man
      <li>woman
      <li>body
      <li>girl
      <li>baby
      </font>
</li>

and thanks
```

Comment: `<font>` is an ancient tag and **its deprecated**. Also `LI` is not a valid child of anything else than `OL, UL, MENU` - Learn your HTML tags.

Comment: Also, that HTML is completely invalid. You need to close each of those `li` tags with a `<\li>`

Answer (score 0):

None of the three examples of lists given in the question is valid HTML so there is not really any point in trying to find out why they give different results. Browsers will do their best to interpret what they are given but there's no guarantee on how each will behave if the structure does not make sense.

The two most important things to notice about the code given in the question are:

1. font has long been deprecated as an HTML tag. Nowadays use CSS. For more information read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)
2. li tags can only be used in lists. And each needs to be terminated before the next one in any particular list.

Assuming the requirement is to color all the list items blue we put them in a list (this snippet assumes an unordered list is what is wanted) where the style is set to `color: blue`. For this snippet the CSS is inline but for many applications moving it to a class defined in a style element would be the more normal route.

```html
<ul style="color: blue;">
  <li>man</li>
  <li>woman</li>
  <li>body</li>
  <li>girl</li>
  <li>baby</li>
</ul>
```